# how to detect infrastructure problems?

Tags: mysql-5.6

I'm new as MySQL and DBA role.

Our systems started to fail due to timeout established by SLA (a few seconds).

Nothing different happened that day, normal usage, less than a thousand transactions per second.

It turns out, database storage reported a latency up to 390ms!!!!

How will we diagnostic this issue without the report from our provider?

We ask for this report after seeing load average 4 times as usual and I/O waits for over 70%.

What should I have done?

Comment: I'm assuming your measurements where from iostat? That should be sufficient to report a problem. If you have a similar independent storage provided you could test with simple iobench/hdlatency tools. Having a complete monitoring solution in place will help show relative performance.

Comment: In case that some rogue query is the root cause, I suggest using the [_slowlog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) .